# how to clear paste value from placeholder in jquery.amsify.suggestags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using `jquery.amsify.suggestags` and I have a problem when pasting in tags from the clipboard.

After pasting, the placeholder text is not cleared, as can be seen in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHSod.png).

I want to clear my input area after paste string in the input area.

I am using this code to bind to the paste event:

```
$(this.selectors.sTagsInput).bind('paste', function(e) {
    var str = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    $(this).val('');
    var res;
    res = str.split(" ");
    var map = "";
    var value = $.trim($(this).val().replace(/,/g, ''));
    var res_rmsp = res.filter(function(value) {
        return value != ""
    });
    $.each(res_rmsp, function(index, val) {
        if (val[0] != "#") {
            map += "#" + val;
        } else {
            map += val;
        }
    });
    res = map.split("#");
    var data = res.filter(function(value) {
        return value != ""
    });
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
        _self.addTag(_self.getValue("#" + val));
    });
    if (_self.settings.showAllSuggestions) {
        _self.suggestWhiteList('', 0, true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Pawan. Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would help people answering if you add more detail about what you have tried so far. From your code example, it looks like you've tried quite a few approaches.

Comment: actually i try to  make instagram hash tags when any string pasted in input area . and then split it into array then add tag through add tag function but i don't understand how to clear pasted value after create tags (Ex image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHSod.png )   .i am using 
jquery.amsify.suggestags library.